# Wagtail installation: Wagtail command not found

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am trying to install [wagtail](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wagtail/). As the docs suggest, I installed wagtail using pip:

```
tigran@tigran:~/projects/website$ pip install wagtail
Collecting wagtail
  Using cached wagtail-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting html5lib<1,>=0.999 (from wagtail)
  Using cached html5lib-0.999999999-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Django<1.12,>=1.8.1 (from wagtail)
  Using cached Django-1.11.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting djangorestframework<3.7,>=3.1.3 (from wagtail)
  Using cached djangorestframework-3.6.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting django-treebeard<5.0,>=3.0 (from wagtail)
Collecting Pillow>=2.6.1 (from wagtail)
  Using cached Pillow-5.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting Unidecode>=0.04.14 (from wagtail)
  Using cached Unidecode-1.0.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting django-taggit<1.0,>=0.20 (from wagtail)
  Using cached django_taggit-0.22.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting django-modelcluster<4.0,>=3.1 (from wagtail)
Collecting Willow<1.1,>=1.0 (from wagtail)
  Using cached Willow-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting beautifulsoup4>=4.5.1 (from wagtail)
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting requests<3.0,>=2.11.1 (from wagtail)
  Using cached requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six (from html5lib<1,>=0.999->wagtail)
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting webencodings (from html5lib<1,>=0.999->wagtail)
  Using cached webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools>=18.5 (from html5lib<1,>=0.999->wagtail)
  Using cached setuptools-38.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz (from Django<1.12,>=1.8.1->wagtail)
  Using cached pytz-2017.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests<3.0,>=2.11.1->wagtail)
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests<3.0,>=2.11.1->wagtail)
  Using cached urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests<3.0,>=2.11.1->wagtail)
  Using cached certifi-2017.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests<3.0,>=2.11.1->wagtail)
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, webencodings, setuptools, html5lib, pytz, Django, djangorestframework, django-treebeard, Pillow, Unidecode, django-taggit, django-modelcluster, Willow, beautifulsoup4, idna, urllib3, certifi, chardet, requests, wagtail
Successfully installed Django-1.11.9 Pillow-5.0.0 Unidecode-1.0.22 Willow-1.0 beautifulsoup4-4.6.0 certifi-2017.11.5 chardet-3.0.4 django-modelcluster-3.1 django-taggit-0.22.2 django-treebeard-4.2.0 djangorestframework-3.6.4 html5lib-0.999999999 idna-2.6 pytz-2017.3 requests-2.18.4 setuptools-38.4.0 six-1.11.0 urllib3-1.22 wagtail-1.13.1 webencodings-0.5.1
```

But when I try to create a project I get the following error:

```
tigran@tigran:~/projects/website$ wagtail start website
wagtail: command not found
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you run both commands in the same virtualenv? What OS are you using?

Comment: Have you got wagtail added to your installed apps in settings.py? Is your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE enviromental variable pointing to the correct settings.py?

Comment: tomd, running on my ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: wobbily_col, i dont have settings.py, i thought wagtail should generate it no?

Comment: and did you run both commands in the same virtualenv?

Comment: tomd, i dont have any virtual env installed. Website will be in docker containers when i have project structure.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that it's installing the `wagtail` command into a location that's not recognised by Ubuntu as a valid place for executables (possibly /usr/local/bin/ ? I seem to recall that Ubuntu doesn't add that by default). I'd recommend using a virtualenv https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation/ , which will hopefully avoid that issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would guess @gasman's comment is correct. Running the getting started commands outside of a virtualenv does produce this issue for me too in Ubuntu 16.04.

You need to create and activate a virtualenv for it to work. Assuming you already have virtualenv installed:

```
mkdir myproject && cd myproject
virtualenv yourvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3
source yourvirtualenv/bin/activate
pip install wagtail
wagtail start website
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to use the -m venv command that comes built-in with Python 3.6 and above.

Check Python version

```
python --version
```

Create venv and install requirements

```
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Try running the wagtail command after the installation is complete.